# How to make css element opacity switches from 0 to 1 in no time?

Tags: css

I am wondering whether there is already a way through CSS in order to make an element of opacity 0 turns to 1 without any transition time. In other words, I need to make an element which was totally unseen suddenly appears after 4 seconds. No fade-in or out. Just appear with the complete brighteness (opacity).

Comment: After 4 seconds of what? Or rather, 4 seconds after what?

Comment: I mean 4 seconds after the page has been loaded, the elemnt should suddenly appears , without the usage of fade-in.

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of visibility and opacity:

```
transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
```

In this demo, hovering over the menu displays only after 0.5s.

http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337#example5

Simple step-to-end transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/7EsKK/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however what happens with this solution is that the opacity is then set to 0 and never turns to 1 and thus the element never appears